# Convert String representation of bytes to byte[] in java

Tags: java, string, arrays

My application get the String representation of bytes. I need to convert it byte[] array. I am using below code but it is not working.

```
byte[] bytesArray = myString.getBytes();
```

Can anyone help what is the correct way to convert it to `byte[]`.

EDIT:

hi all, My code is here http://pastebin.com/87jGprtD/. I have one base64 code. This base64 has content for text and imagedata both. I want to download/create an image from this code. When I decode I get the byte[] for both text and imagedata. I convert it string because I have to differentiate the each part. I used spilt with some delimiter now i have an array of string. This string contains the imagedata. I have to convert it back to bytes to create an image. please check code for the same. please

Here is the relevant code:

```
byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString);
System.out.println(new String(imageByteArray));
String[] contentArray = new String(imageByteArray).split("--1_520B30B0_E358708");
for (int i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
    if (i == 2) {
        String[] parts = contentArray[i].split("binary");
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream((parts[1].trim()).getBytes());
        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is);
        System.out.println(iis);
        image = ImageIO.read(iis);
        ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("E:/test1.JPG"));
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am getting wrong output. Actually it 28kb of bytes when I use above line it converting to 47kb. I checked the length of arrays.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: So long as there is a platform "default character set", `getBytes()` should work.  If it's not working you need to show us a specific example, with code to reproduce.

Comment: @VanajaGoud: The problem is that there is no uniform way to represent characters (ASCII/Unicode/...). In case one uses unicode, it's very likely the size differs.

Comment: @CommuSoft - The code should "work" regardless.  It may not return the "expected" results, but that's an entirely different matter.

Comment: @HotLicks: True, That's more or less the content of the comment.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "String representation of bytes", especially since it sounds like what you're trying to get is the byte representation in strings -- which, as others have said, requires that you specify the encoding, and which may result in an array longer than the string if the encoding of a character is either variable-length (as in UTF8) or multibyte, or a combination of the two (as in UTF16).

Comment: @keshlam -- The byte array *will not* be twice as long, but will be translated from UTF16 to bytes using the default character set.

Comment: Vanaja, you **must** show us some of your original data.  I suspect you mean that you have (erroneously) received "binary" data into a `String`.  If this is the case you can't "fix" it by converting to `byte[]`, but must instead correct your code to never convert to `String` in the first place.

Comment: @HotLicks: Valid point, but given the numbers being quoted (byte array about 2x the length of character array), it sounds like the default character set *is* UTF16 on this user's platform. Either that or the Unicode string is mostly characters above the ASCII range.

Comment: hi all, My code is here [link](http://pastebin.com/87jGprtD). I have one base64 code. This base64 has content for text and imagedata both. I want to download/create an image from this code. When I decode I get the byte[] for both text and imagedata. I convert it string because I have to differentiate the each part. I used spilt with some delimiter now i have an array of string. This string contains the imagedata. I have to convert it back to bytes to create an image. please check code for the same. please

Comment: 'Because I have to differentiate the each part' is meaningless, and you've been told several times that you must post the code ***here.*** -1

Comment: @EJP I cant paste more than 30000 char code here. I have base64 code string in my code. It is too big so I used other link.

Comment: Paste the relevant code here.  It should only be a dozen lines or so, I suspect.  And, as I said, you SHOULD NOT convert decoded "binary" to String.  You may place Base64 in a String, since that's character data, but once the Base64 is converted back to `byte[]` you must not convert to String.

Answer (score 0):

You are decoding Base64 data into `byte[]`, then converting that to `String`.  You can't do that -- "binary" data cannot be converted to `String` and back to "binary" without data loss.